# Multiple selection criteria/dropdowns to links

Tags: html, dropdown

I need to have 2 drop down selections, the user picks 1 from each - and then a submit button to match those 2 results to a certain youtube video.

For example:

Each dropdown could have "Mom", "Dad", "kid1", and "kid2" - each combo would link to a different video after clicking the submit button (that would have those 2 people in it).

I can't figure out how to essentially have a series of if/then statements based on the dropdown selections.

so like

```
if var1=Mom and var2=kid1 then youtubeurl=whatever1  

if var1=Mom and var2=kid2 then youtubeurl=whatever2
```

etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Post effort and CODE in a [mcve]

Comment: Do you have any code to show? How are you planning on doing these if then statements, with Javascript? Get us some more info so we can help you.

Comment: Post some code, show us what you've tried.

Comment: You have two dropdown menues and how many options in each dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with HTML only

You need JavaScript

```js
var vids = {
  mombro: "vid1",
  momsis: "vid2",
  dadbro: "vid3",
  dadsis: "vid4",
}
window.onload=function() { // page has loaded
  var sels = document.querySelectorAll(".sel"); // get all sels
  for (var i=0;i<sels.length;i++) { // add event handler to each
    sels[i].onchange=function() { // when any select changes
      var val = document.getElementById("sel1").value +
                document.getElementById("sel2").value;
      console.log(vids[val] || "invalid combo");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="sel" id="sel1">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="mom">Mom</option>
  <option value="dad">Dad</option>
</select>
<select class="sel" id="sel2">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="bro">Brother</option>
  <option value="sis">Sister</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

I presume you are using Javascript,

Check out the MDN page on "else if" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

var youtubeurl;

```
if(var1=="Mom" && var2=="kid1"){
  youtubeurl=whatever1; 
} else if(var1=="Mom" && var2=="kid2"){
  youtubeurl=whatever2;
}
```

or you could do,

```
if(var1=="Mom"){
  if(var2=="kid1"){
    youtubeurl=whatever1;
  } else if(var2=="kid2"){
    youtubeurl=whatever2;
  }
}
```